# How to run .Net core WinForms application on Linux

Tags: linux, winforms, debian, .net-core-3.1

So I have created a test .net core 3.1 WinForms application on Windows. It's an .exe application. I have copied it to my Debian VM and installed .net core 3.1 runtime.  When I double click on it to run then I get the following screen:

[image]

How do I run this .exe application?

Comment: .NET Core doesn’t support WinForms on other platforms than Windows

Answer (score 0):

I would have commented to ask first but I don't have that privilege.

Do you have anything installed to run exe applications? If not, try installing a compatibility layer  such as [Wine for Debian](https://wiki.winehq.org/Debian) which would allow your system to understand the format. From my research, Wine should be able to interpret your .net core version.

If you already have Wine, then just ignore me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take your source code to a linux machine and compile it there with Mono. EXE files will only run with a compatibility layer like wine. See https://markheath.net/post/running-windows-forms-on-linux-with-mono for an explanation how to compile .net applications with winforms for linux